# Con el widget Text en Tkinter, se obtienen valores distintos en len

Tags: tkinter

Como se notará, necesito saber si se produjeron cambios (no grabados), y de ser así emitir un mensaje. Lo que ocurre que sin efectuar ningún cambio `len` me da 45 (para el text) y 44 (para lo extraído del archivo).
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import codecs
import re
from functools import partial


def obtenerCopia():
    with codecs.open('Copia.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as archivo:
        mensaje = archivo.read()
        return mensaje 


def on_closing(copia):
    leer = textEt.get(1.0, "end")
    print(f"{len(leer)} - {len(copia)}")
    root.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x300+500+300")

copiaTmp = obtenerCopia()
copia = copiaTmp.strip()


textEt=tk.Text(root, height=10, width=47, font=("Verdana", 12))
textEt.place(x=10, y=10)
textEt.insert(1.0, copia)


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", partial(on_closing, copia))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Esta respuesta, del sitio en ingles, responde tu duda? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62360461/12913664

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que el widget text pone un salto de línea al final, por lo tanto al comparar lo extraído del txt(sin salto de línea) y text daba distinto y yo sabia que no había efectuado cambios.-

```
t.get('1.0',"end-1c")
```

Comment: Evita dejar agradecimientos y saludos en tu respuesta. En su lugar, pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo responde esto a tu pregunta. Recuerda que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para ti, sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Lee [answer]. Por último, cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.